# How to navigate with Enter key in QTableView when cell is being edited

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5, keyboard-shortcuts, qtableview

My pyqt layout contain several widget including `qtableview`, `qlineedit`, `qpushbutton` etc. I can navigate through widgets using Tab key, however I am trying to use Enter key (Return) to navigate through 'qtableview'.

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItemModel, QStandardItem
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QShortcut
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
     
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.centralwidget)
        # label name
        self.label_name = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label_name.setText( "Name")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_name)
        # line edit
        self.lineEdit_name = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_name.setObjectName("lineEdit_name")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_name)
       
        #tableview
        self.tableView = QtWidgets.QTableView(self.centralwidget)
        # create tablemodel
        self.table_model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.table_model.setHorizontalHeaderLabels( ["Item", "Unit", "unitPrice", "Unit*unitPrice"])
        self.table_model.insertRow(0)
        self.tableView.setModel(self.table_model)
        # keyboard shortcut activation
        self.shortcut = QShortcut(QKeySequence("Return"), MainWindow)
        self.shortcut.activated.connect(self.on_enter)

        
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableView)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    def on_enter(self):
        print('hasFocus '+ str(self.tableView.hasFocus()))
        if(self.tableView.hasFocus()):
            self.tableView.focusNextChild()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

`tableview.hasFocus()` is used, in order to check whether focus is on `tableview` or not. The issue I am facing here is that, when I click on any cell `self.tableView.hasFocus()` return `False`, which dose not activate `self.tableView.focusNextChild()` and I can not naviagte further using Enter key. If I don't use `if(self.tableView.hasFocus()):` it may leads to naviagtion through other widgets like `qlineedit`. How can I use Enter key to navigate through my table cell?

Test 1 : curser on lineEdit, press Enter on Keyboard => print: hasFocus False

[image]

Test 2 : selected the table cell. press Enter key => print: hasFocus True
[image]

Test 3 : clicked on cell (curser visible), press Enter key=> print: hasFocus False
[image]

Here I am satisficed with test 1 and test2. However, in test 3 the `hasFocus()` shows `False`, so when I press Enter key the courser dose not come out of table from edit mode. Then I need to use tab key to come out of edit mode, is it possible to get out of edit mode by pressing Enter key

Comment: @eyllanesc, Thank you for commenting, it is difficult for me to explain the problem. Basically I need to use `Enter` key to navigate through the tableview

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When a cell is being edited, a separate editing widget is shown which takes the keyboard focus. Your example can be fixed by testing whether this widget is open:

```
def on_enter(self):
    if (self.tableView.hasFocus() or
        self.tableView.isPersistentEditorOpen(self.tableView.currentIndex())):
        self.tableView.focusNextChild()
```

(NB: [isPersistentEditorOpen](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#isPersistentEditorOpen) requires Qt >= 5.10)

Comment: thank you, now I can navigate using Enter Key